# LSASS Activity is Being Flagged as a Potentially Compromised Host - How should I investigate this?

Tags: windows, investigation

We've recently been seeing new security events being flagged to the SOC for activity involving LSASS usage from the wmiprvse.exe process across multiple Windows servers. We've investigated the wmiprvse.exe process by reviewing the process ID and found it to be the legitimate version of the process.

The leading belief in the department is that there is a legitimate application requiring LSASS in order to function properly, but we're keen to have this confirmed conclusively.

We've tried contacting our SIEM vendor to

- Are there any other steps we should be performing to confirm that this is business as usual/false positive activity?
- Has anyone else found the same activity being flagged by SIEMs?

Please see below the raw event log indicating the wmiprvse.exe process is calling LSASS:

```
<13>Dec 17 07:36:29 [hostname] 
AgentDevice=WindowsLog
AgentLogFile=Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon/Operational   
PluginVersion=[version number]  
Source=Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon 
Computer=[comp. name]   
OriginatingComputer=[IP Address]    
User=SYSTEM 
Domain=NT AUTHORITY 
EventID=18  
EventIDCode=18  
EventType=4 
EventCategory=18    
RecordNumber=[removed]  
TimeGenerated=1576568188    
TimeWritten=1576568188  
Level=Informational 
Keywords=0x8000000000000000 
Task=SysmonTask-SYSMON_CONNECT_NAMEDPIPE    
Opcode=Info 
Message=Pipe Connected: RuleName:  EventType: ConnectPipe UtcTime: 2019-12-17 07:36:28.875 ProcessGuid: {352CC6C8-3182-5DF5-0000-0010DFFC0700} ProcessId: 4852 PipeName: \lsass Image: C:\Windows\system32\wbem\wmiprvse.exe
```

Comment: The log in your post is a sysmon event id 18, concerning the use of a named pipe. Basically, it says that wmiprvse.exe is communicating using a named pipe called lsass. **This is suspicious**. However, this raw log isn't enough to give you more details into what exactly happened. Also, wmiprvse.exe is a host process for CommandLine event consumers, so even if it is legitimate, it might host malicious processes

Comment: Since you have sysmon, check if you have instances of EventID 10 targeting lsass.exe

Comment: That's Microsoft for you. Absolute trash of operating system design in terms of security. Indeed WmiPrvSE does open a handle to lsass, even sometimes with the maximum access_mask.. when there is absolutely no need for it to even openning handle to lsass..